# Redirect link for multiple store

Tags: multistore, knockoutjs, redirect, language

I have a small problem and don't know how to implement redirect based on selected language (as a multiple store views there are few languages: en, lt,lv). The file located in
app/design/frontend/MyProject/Project/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/content.html and the code that need to be changed

```
<ifnot args="getCartParam('summary_count')">
    <div class="empty-bag-img"></div>
            <strong class=""
                    translate="'You have no items in your shopping cart.'"></strong>
            <div class="actions">
                <div class="secondary">
                    <a class="action viewcart" href="/">
                        <span translate="'Go to the store'"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
</ifnot>
```

For know it hardcoded and redirect to home without saving language.
Could you help with several steps what I should do to make redirect like home.com/en or home.com/lv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve this problem.simply add this code with baseUrl into minicart.js.

```
return Component.extend({
        shoppingCartUrl: window.checkout.shoppingCartUrl,
        baseUrl: window.checkout.baseUrl,
```

app/design/frontend/MyProject/Project/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/content.html

```
 <div class="actions">
            <div class="secondary">
                <a class="action viewcart" data-bind="attr: { href: baseUrl }">
                    <span translate="'Go to the store'"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

please try the below code.

```
<a class="action viewcart" data-bind="attr: { href: getBaseUrl() }">
  <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Home page' --><!-- /ko --></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can use it is to check the below code and try to implement it.

/var/www/html/project/app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="additional_provider_class" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\AdditionalConfig</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

/var/www/html/walletmetamask/app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/AdditionalConfig.php

```
<?php
  namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

  use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;
  use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;
  use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart as CustomerCart;



class AdditionalConfig implements ConfigProviderInterface
 {

protected $checkoutSession;

protected $cart;

protected $storeManager;


/**
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
 * @param \Web30india\Faq\Helper\Data $helper
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    CustomerCart $cart,
    CheckoutSession $checkoutSession
   
   
) {
    $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->cart = $cart;
}

public function getConfig()
{
    $validationConfig = [
         "baseUrl" => $this->getBaseUrl()
    ];

    return $validationConfig;
}

public function getBaseUrl(){
     return $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB);
}

}
```

In the HTML file add the below code

/var/www/html/project/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/payment/web3wallet.html

```
<a data-bind="attr: {'href': checkoutConfig.baseUrl}" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

you can use more information.

```
checkout.baseUrl => {www.example.com}/

checkout.checkoutUrl => {www.example.com}/checkout/

checkout.customerLoginUrl => {www.example.com}/customer/account/login/

checkout.removeItemUrl => {www.example.com}/checkout/sidebar/removeItem/

checkout.shoppingCartUrl => {www.example.com}/checkout/cart/

checkout.updateItemQtyUrl => {www.example.com}/checkout/sidebar/updateItemQty/

checkoutConfig.cartUrl => {www.example.com}/checkout/cart/

checkoutConfig.checkoutUrl => {www.example.com}/checkout/

checkoutConfig.defaultSuccessPageUrl => {www.example.com}/checkout/onepage/success/

checkoutConfig.forgotPasswordUrl => {www.example.com}/customer/account/forgotpassword/

checkoutConfig.pageNotFoundUrl => {www.example.com}/checkout/noroute/

checkoutConfig.registerUrl => {www.example.com}/customer/account/create/

checkoutConfig.staticBaseUrl => {www.example.com}/pub/static/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="action viewcart" href="/"> => <a class="action viewcart" href="#" id="goToStoreLink">

<script type="text/javascript">
require([
'jquery',
'mage/translate',
'mage/url'
], function ($, $t, urlBuilder) {
var currentLanguage = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
var goToStoreLink = $('#goToStoreLink');
var languageCode = currentLanguage.substr(0, 2);
var storeUrlMap = {
'en': '/en/',
'de': '/de/',
'fr': '/fr/'
};
goToStoreLink.attr('href', urlBuilder.build(storeUrlMap[languageCode]));
});
</script>
</ifnot>
```